# How to use Html.BeginForm in subfolder

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

This is code that work on localhost.

Views Notification/Index.cshtml :

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Index","Notification",FormMethod.Post))
{
 ...
```

But It isn't work on server. 
When I click submit button this is url.

```
http://test.com/Notification
```

And I want this url.

```
http://test.com/subfolder/Notification
```

It has subfolder because I use docker on server.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Html.BeginForm("Index", "Notification", new {area="subfolder"}, FormMethod.Post)
```

But I recomend you to rewrite your code with [TagHelpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms).